# Thor & YAML outputting as binary?

Tags: ruby, yaml, thor

I'm using Thor and trying to output YAML to a file.  In irb I get what I expect.  Plain text in YAML format.  But when part of a method in Thor, its output is different...

```
class Foo < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  desc "bar", "test"
  def set
    test = {"name" => "Xavier", "age" => 30}
    puts test
    # {"name"=>"Xavier", "age"=>30}
    puts test.to_yaml
    # !binary "bmFtZQ==": !binary |-
    #   WGF2aWVy
    # !binary "YWdl": 30
    File.open("data/config.yml", "w") {|f| f.write(test.to_yaml) }
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I just ran your example and it gave me perfectly fine output. I ran thor 0.14.6.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to check.  I'm at a loss of what to do at this point. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p125 if that makes any difference what so ever. :)

Comment: I installed 1.9.3 and ran it again, and indeed binary output. I noticed YAML got upgraded during install. It probably has something to do with that upgraded version.

Comment: Thanks Maran. I assume yaml is built into ruby, would it be easier to rvm install 1.9.2 rather than install 1.9.3 w/ the downgraded version of yaml?

Comment: Yeah, as soon as I issue rvm 1.9.2 everything works again, yaml wise. If you don't _need_ 1.9.3 I would switch back to 1.9.2

Comment: I tried it using Ruby 1.9.3p0 and Thor 0.14.6 and it generates perfect yaml for me. Could it be the difference between p0 and p125?

Comment: Adding `#encoding: UTF-8` to the top of the file seems to fix it. I don't know what's going on though - it looks like thor is changing the default encoding to ASCII-8BIT and then [a change to yaml in Ruby 1.9.3](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/commit/c9cd187d5aa8fa6607dd463b5f98a65483ae39ce) causes the output to be binary.

Comment: I think it's due to how thor reads in `.thor` files; it uses [`File.binread`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-binread) which sets the encoding to ASCII-8BIT.

Answer (score 14):

All Ruby 1.9 strings have an encoding attached to them.

YAML encodes some non-UTF8 strings as binary, even when they look innocent, without any high-bit characters. You might think that your code is always using UTF8, but builtins can return non-UTF8 strings (ex File path routines).

To avoid binary encoding, make sure all your strings encodings are UTF-8 before calling to_yaml. Change the encoding with force_encoding("UTF-8") method.

For example, this is how I encode my options hash into yaml:

```
options = {
    :port => 26000,
    :rackup => File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "../sveg.rb"))
}
utf8_options = {}
options.each_pair { |k,v| utf8_options[k] = ((v.is_a? String) ? v.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v)}
puts utf8_options.to_yaml
```

Here is an example of yaml encoding simple strings as binary

```
>> x = "test"
=> "test"
>> x.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
>> x.to_yaml
=> "--- test\n...\n"
>> x.force_encoding "ASCII-8BIT"
=> "test"
>> x.to_yaml
=> "--- !binary |-\n  dGVzdA==\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

After version 1.9.3p125, ruby build-in YAML engine will treat all BINARY encoding differently than before. All you need to do is to set correct non-BINARY encoding before your String.to_yaml.

in Ruby 1.9, All String object have attached a Encoding object
and as following blog ( by James Edward Gray II ) mentioned, ruby have build in three type of encoding when String is generated:
http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings.

One of encoding may solve your problem => Source code Encoding

This is the encoding of your source code, and can be specify by adding magic encoding string at the first line or second line ( if you have a sha-bang string at the first line of your source code )
  the magic encoding code could be one of following:

- # encoding: utf-8
- # coding: utf-8
- # -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-

so in your case, if you use ruby 1.9.3p125 or later, this should be solved by adding one of magic encoding in the beginning of your code.

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'thor'
class Foo < Thor
  include Thor::Actions

  desc "bar", "test"
  def bar
    test = {"name" => "Xavier", "age" => 30}
    puts test
    #{"name"=>"Xavier", "age"=>30}
    puts test["name"].encoding.name
    #UTF-8
    puts test.to_yaml
    #---
    #name: Xavier
    #age: 30
    puts test.to_yaml.encoding.name
    #UTF-8
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this using 1.9.3p545 on Windows - just with a simple hash containing strings - and no Thor.

The gem [ZAML](https://rubygems.org/gems/zaml) solves the problem quite simply:

```
require 'ZAML'
yaml = ZAML.dump(some_hash)
File.write(path_to_yaml_file, yaml)
```