# Evernote API Binary Error - Ruby on Rails - OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, evernote

I am trying to take the Evernote Ruby example https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ruby which uses Sinatra and integrate it into Rails.

I have everything working fine until pulling a list of notebooks in the callback.

```
notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(access_token.token)
result = Array.new
notebooks.each do |notebook| 
  result << notebook.name
end
@notebooks = result
```

It's getting this error: (which isn't helpful at all)

```
RuntimeError in CallbacksController#callback

--- !binary |-
U1NMX2Nvbm5lY3QgcmV0dXJuZWQ9MSBlcnJubz0wIHN0YXRlPVNTTHYzIHJl
YWQgc2VydmVyIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIEI6IGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIHZlcmlmeSBm
YWlsZWQ=
```

The Sinatra app works correctly. So my guess is that some file is not being loaded to parse this. But I have tried everything.

I will post the full controller here: http://paste.codebasehq.com/pastes/7frtcdhyncwb0emznj

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace?

Comment: @rossta http://paste.codebasehq.com/pastes/g58udmy5ihwfv4kggs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `to_yml` makes your error message unreadable like:

```
--- !binary |-
U1NMX2Nvbm5lY3QgcmV0dXJuZWQ9MSBlcnJubz0wIHN0YXRlPVNTTHYzIHJl
YWQgc2VydmVyIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIEI6IGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIHZlcmlmeSBm
YWlsZWQ=
```

Can you replace `to_yml` with `inspect`?
It seems simply your message is outputted as binary and you could figure out the cause of error from messages if it is outputted as text.

Related post:
[Thor & YAML outputting as binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550330/thor-yaml-outputting-as-binary)